# Deploying ASP.net on IIS in windows 7

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've never actually used IIS, and I'm pretty new to the whole ASP.net thing too.

Basically, I've created a RESTful service using a VS2010 ASP.net project.
I'm not sure how you get that ASP.net application (which runs great on Visual Studio) to run on an IIS server. 
It's pretty easy with a Java dynamic web project and Tomcat, but here I'm not sure how to begin.

Do I simply deploy the binaries to a directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ther are some possibilities

the easy one

create under c:\inetpub\wwwroot\  a new directory for your app

in the iis manager, configure this directory (create an application, set the right .net version, ... ). than everything you need is to copy all your files into that directory and thats it.

but you can also create a msi file, if you don't have the direct access to the server.

hth

Answer (score 2):

For best testing you application use IIS 7.5 express on you development machine and set this:
project->Properties->Web->Use Local IIS Web Server

After testing under local IIS you can deploy you project to real IIS by using Build->Publish 'Your project'
Simplest way is deploying to File System in some folder and copy its content to created site folder, associated with IIS Virtual directory. To create Sites and virtual directories, see this:

http://www.bloggingdeveloper.com/post/Creating-IIS7-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-using-Internet-Information-Services-Manager.aspx

http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/07/12/Creating-IIS7-sites_2C00_-applications_2C00_-and-virtual-directories.aspx